# Wife's mother asking her to give khula

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, talaq

Assalamualaikum
My question is regarding wife seeking khula and the reason here for it is that she lives in USA and I live in India and her parents are forcing her to ask khula from me by giving her the reason that I cannot come there they have asked lawyers about my visa and all of them said there is only 2% chance of getting visa (my in-laws haven't applied for visa they just asked lawyers) so my wife said she'll wait or come to me and I'm all ready to welcome her in my home so her mother states that she's going to tear her passport and don't let her go. Then my mother in law gave another reason to ask khula which was he doesn't give you money and bear your expenses and she asked my wife to ask me 3000$ every month tho my wife knows I'm not rich nor I've that much money to bear her expenses according to USA lifestyle but she knows and I'm good enough to bear her expenses and daily need or basic needs of life if she's with me. And the main reason they are forcing her to ask divorce is that my in laws hate me because we did love marriage after going thru many struggles and made this relationship halal by nikah and we both know the value of our marriage and we don't need it to break please guide us

Comment: These complex personal issues are best taken to an expert rather than online like this.

Answer (score -1):

Walaikum Us Salaam Wa Rahmatullahi Wa Barakaatuhu!
First of all, sorry to say that, according to Islamic Shariah. The nikah was not fulfilled for a woman without her *Wali* (Father, Brother or any other close male relative), but in your case, there is confusion that the nikah should be fulfilled by the permission from your wife's male relative.
Otherwise, you should keep struggling to protect your marriage with lots of patience and do ask *Khair* from Allah Subhanahu Wa Ta'ala.
InShaAllah, you will not disappoint.
My suggestion is that you should not give *Khula* to your wife. You should convince her to bring her to your side.
May Allah helps you both regarding your marriage life. (Ameen)

Comment: First it is out of question whether nikah was fulfilled as OP actually starts from the position that they are legally married else why should there be a khul'a issue. Secondly khul'a is done via court.